# PyQt4 : Can I intercept the currentIndexChanged signal of QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qcombobox

I build up a UI consisted of QComboBox and QGraphicsScene and it's QGraphicsItems.

When I change the index of QComboBox, refresh QGraphicsScene so it set to default. To solve it, I store a geometry info to a node. It works well.

At this time, I want to determine that QGraphicsItems are modified, and their geo-infos are not stored. So, UI notice to user that he or she have to store them.

I want that it happens when change QComboBox, and to do that I have to intercept the currentIndexChanged signal. It means that before QComboBox change the index actually, it read the flag and do something to user, and not to miss the geo-infos QComboBox return to previous index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand.

Do you want to know the previous index before the current index changes? If so, then keep a record of the previous index:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._previous_index = -1

def handleCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
    # do stuff with previous_index (if valid)
    ...
    self._previous_index = index
```

Comment: yes, I tried that "previous index". But, "currentIndexChanged" emit after index changed. So back to previous index means that call "currentIndexChanged" signal once again, it seems loop. I think it is not sophisticated :)

Comment: @Hyun-geunKim. It's hard to understand what you want. Could you show some example code?

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro! I just wrote the script using you suggested. I need another flag to back to previous index